# Apple keyboard and XF86AudioPlay media key in Linux

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, fedora, i3-window-manager

I have external apple keyboard and I have a problem of mapping XF86AudioPlay key. All the other keys for controlling brightness, music volume, mute, audio next, audio prev work well. This is the only one. Does anyone know how to map it?

I'm using fedora 26 and i3 WM.

*update:*

The output of `xev` upon the key press is:

`KeymapNotify event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0

           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0`

Answer (score 1):

As I'm a newbie and therefore can't ask for further details, let me simply suggest using the `xev` command to look up the actual keysim of the play button. Once you've got that, simply adapt your config file (`~/.config/i3/config`) accordingly.

You find a further description of changing the keybindings in the [i3 User's Guide](https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#keybindings).

Comment: Anything more than this is most likely overkill. I must assume that fikovnik and anybody else running into such a problem knows the basics about i3's config file and maybe copied a slightly incompatible example from the web. In that case a simple instruction on how to bind the according keysim should suffice.

Comment: I tried `xev` before and I did not see anything useful (cf. above).